# Resolve Cannot mix aggregate and non aggregate comparisons or results in if tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm very new to tableau, and working on a dashboard currently. I trying to create the  calculated field for YTD severity. When I try this below formula, it gives aggregate error. Any thoughts or workaround will be much helpful.

Thanks in Advance

```
  if year([ClaimOpenDate]) = YEAR(TODAY()) then sum([TotalLossPaid])/COUNTD([ClaimNum]) end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, most new users have this issue. If you aggregate any dim or measure, all must be aggregated. In your calc, ClaimOpenDate is missing it's aggregation, wrap it in the attr function: attr([ClaimOpenDate])